# curl inside VM sometimes hangs

Tags: curl, libvirt, virt-manager

I've created a domain with Virtual Machine Manager that runs Ubuntu 20. It is on a part of a virtual network with NAT forwarding and I have the internet connectivity but `curl` command sometimes hangs.
For example `curl -sL run.linkerd.io/install | sh` download doesn't start 9/10 times and then when it does start, it hangs on the next step ('Download complete!')
Also I've been having problem with downloading helm charts...
Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: bad internet connectivity, wrong networking setup, half-set-up IPv6, misconfigured proxy,…

Comment: ... [PMTUD failing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_MTU_Discovery#Problems) along the path to some mirror and not some other mirror of the same resource...